# ASIHTTPRequest does not download the zip file

Tags: iphone, ios, url, zip, asihttprequest

I have to download a zip file from a url, after I unzip. The file in question I put it in the Documents folder. It does not quite download.
this is the code:

```
 NSURL *urltoZip = [NSURL URLWithString: urlZip]; 

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 NSString *filePathAndDirectory1 = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/ZipPackages"]];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePathAndDirectory1])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory1 withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

 NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [filePathAndDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", self.nomePackage]];


if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePathAndDirectory])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];


NSLog(@"fileName zip %@", filePathAndDirectory);
/*  fileName zip   /var/mobile/Applications/5256198E-72FC-4054-BFD3-BC1600BDC01C/Documents/ZipPackages/HtmlInfo */

ASIHTTPRequest *requestZip = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:urltoZip];
[requestZip setDownloadDestinationPath:filePathAndDirectory]; //in this path is not saved anything
[requestZip startSynchronous];

response =[requestZip responseString];

  NSLog(@" response zip  %@", response);
  /*response zip 

     <!DOCTYPE html>

     <html lang="en">

      <head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>

       ..........

       </footer>

      </form>

    </body>

    </html>*/
```

In the Documents folder there is no trace of the file. How can I do?

Comment: By your last NSLog i guess that you are not downloading zip file but html page that allows download of that file. To ensure that you have right url, open the url in browser and see if file download starts immediately.

Comment: I corrected the url, but it is still saved. I have done something wrong in the build folders?

Answer (score 0):

Int your code:

```
NSString *filePathAndDirectory1 = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/ZipPackages"]];
```

"/" is no needed when you use "stringByAppendingPathComponent:" 
change your code as following:

```
 NSString *filePathAndDirectory1 = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ZipPackages"]];
```

try it again it might work now.